# iOS Pinch to zoom/rotate optimization for small items

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uigesturerecognizer, gestures

I am playing with the pinching/dragging/rotating gestures (working with the gestures, not raw touch events). It works nice, but I have noticed one problem. For pinching/rotating both fingers need to be inside the view. As long as the view is large enough its not a problem, but as soon as the view becomes very small (in regards to the parent thats a scrollview), it feels a little bit like struggle to get the view "back". I have been checking some other apps, and Whatsapp does that the best. When you add a emoticon to an image inside Whatsapp, you can do all the gestures without the need to have both fingers on the view. For example, I made the emoticon really small, put two fingers so that the emoticon lies between them, and the gesture recognizer applies my movement to the emoticon (but not the to the scrollview which is the superview). When I do it inside my App the gestures are being applied to the scrollview as long as I dont place both fingers on the view I want to transform

Is there some setting on the gestures so it does that or do I have to work with raw touch events and calculate my own stuff ?

Thanks

Comment: You should add gesture recognizers in scrollview and then programmatically check touch location. If you see that location is near image - zoom image, if touch location is somewhere else, do something else.

Comment: thats not how it works. On whatsapp you can put the emoticon at the center of ther image and pinch on the most edged, but those gestures would apply to the emoticon (not the the scrollview). I guess the whole area among the two touch events is being processed, and there is a check if some view is inside, if so, apply the transformation to that view. Somehow like that. But I was wondering if there is some out of the box ("apply gestures to children"), or if I need to do it manually